# Neo4J Import Tool Inconsistencies

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher

I've tried searching for documentation to use the "new" neo4j-admin import tool but have not found anything in regards to it's usage compared to the, soon-to-be, deprecated neo4j-import tool.

I receive no fatal errors when using neo4j-import and am able to query the database. The command I use for import is as follows:

`./neo4j-import \
--into /Users/rlinchan/Applications/neo4j-community-3.0.8/data/databases/graph.db/ \
--stacktrace 'true' \
--delimiter "|" \
--array-delimiter ";" \
--quote "\"" \
--bad-tolerance 10000 \
--nodes "/Users/rlinchan/Desktop/v4/nodes/disease_ontology.do.nodes.csv" \
--nodes "/Users/rlinchan/Desktop/v4/nodes/ebi.chebi.nodes.csv" \
--relationships "/Users/rlinchan/Desktop/v4/edges/disease_ontology.do.edges.csv" \
--relationships "/Users/rlinchan/Desktop/v4/edges/ebi.chebi.edges.csv"`

There are many more node and relationship files being loaded (~6 GB of data) but I've excluded them here for brevity. The issue I'm having is, upon a cursory inspection of the data using the Neo4j browser, an inability to see the relationship types in the "Database Information" section.

[image: Relationship types = No relationships in database]

I am able to query the database and receive results in the browser, showing that the relationships do exist. I am not able to modify the color, size, or label of nodes and edges in the Neo4j browser visualizations however, which I need for publication figures. All nodes and edges are gray, and selections of color, size, and label are not applied to the query results.

[image: Color,size,label not applying]

Is this an issue with my data import? I've used this command for the import tool on various other Neo4j versions without fault.

Here are examples of the node files and edge files, if that helps at all:

Node Header
`source_id:ID|name:string|synonyms:string[]|definition:string|:LABEL`
Edge Header
`:START_ID|:TYPE|source:string|:END_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels assigned to node types will throw an error if the label contains special characters, a period in specific.

Previous graph databases I had created worked just fine, regardless the version of Neo4j and I realized it had to be the dataset itself.

Periods in the label must have a naming convention issue within javascript or java itself (usually used for calling classes, properties, methods).
I've simply renamed the labels in my dataset by replacing periods with underscores and coloring, naming, and size modifications in the Neo4j browser are no longer an issue. (See image below)

[Neo4j Browser Modifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NHNz.png) (since I can't post images)

Answer (score 0):

It could just be that some of the metadata in the browser is temporarily out of sync with the server. Try disconnecting from the server using the browser command `:server disconnect`, and then logging back in.

Comment: I have attempted full reinstalls of different versions of Neo4j, tested different browsers, performed partial imports of all my data, and still have had no luck. 
I attempted the `:server disconnect` command you suggested, to exercise due diligence, but to no avail.